# How can I add a image size cap in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this slide show but since images have different lengths and heights it ruins the rest of the html what can I add to make all images the same size.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var timeGap = 5000; // time gap in milliseconds
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

setInterval(function() {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  slideIndex++
}, timeGap)
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/300" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/1000" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: add a class with max-width

Comment: @Ason if the answer is simple as add a width then I am, most of the people I see do. My bad I totally missed the height issue.

Answer (score 1):

If to make each image keep their ratio, and to have them all *fit* into a given space, and with that control the surrounding elements, here is two options:

*Note, for `height`/`max-height` to work properly on the image, each parent need a height constraint, normally done giving each a fixed height. In below samples I added height to parents so it works. There are many other ways to get a height constraint, such as flexbox, grid, absolute positioning, not covered here though.*

Use `object-fit` combined with `width`/`height` set to fill parent.

```
.mySlides img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;           /* used 90% to prevent image from overlap the arrows */
  object-fit: cover;     /* also try "contain" to see what it does */
}
```

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var timeGap = 5000; // time gap in milliseconds
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

setInterval(function() {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  slideIndex++
}, timeGap)
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  height: 80vh;
}
.mySlides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mySlides img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;   /* used 90% to prevent image from overlap the arrows */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/300">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/1000">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

---

Use `max-width` and `min-width`.

```
.mySlides img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;   /* used 90% to prevent image from overlap the arrows */
}
```

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var timeGap = 5000; // time gap in milliseconds
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

setInterval(function() {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  slideIndex++
}, timeGap)
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  height: 80vh;
}
.mySlides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mySlides img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;   /* used 90% to prevent image from overlap the arrows */
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/300">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/1000">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using object-fit, you can also set the images as backgrounds. That will give you a lot of options to play with as well.

I added CSS and removed the image tags.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var timeGap = 5000; // time gap in milliseconds
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

setInterval(function() {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  slideIndex++
}, timeGap)
```

```css
.mySlides {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  
  background-image: var(--background-image);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.mySlides > .numbertext {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/300')">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/300')">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/1000')">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use object-fit css property for you images, [here you can read more.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

**Like:**

```
.mySlides img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `max-width` property. In the example below I set the max-width to 400px

```
<div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
     <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%; max-width: 400px">
</div>
```

Comment: why use inline?